# how to check for duplicate values in listview vb.net

Tags: vb.net

How do i control entry of a record to a listview if it creates duplication,not to a database of course.It checks all the items in the listview including the subitems and then notifies the user that there is a reocrd in the listview if there exists,otherwise recorded
I still can't the right code.

Can you help me out please?

Answer (score 1):

Either bind to a collection that does not allow duplicates (i.e. [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) or loop through the entire list of items before adding to see if the item already exists. I recommend the `HashSet` route, as it will return `False` if you try to add a duplicate item to the collection, thus your code for adding is simplified to this:

```
If hashSet.Add(yourNewValue) Then
    ' Succesfully added
Else
    ' Value already exists, add did not happen
End If
```

Comment: And, it's faster than looping through the entire list.